# Android : onActivityResult doesn't work on TabHost ?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem with calling onActivityResult.
When I call startActivityForResult on normal Activity(with, onActivityResult works.
I mean, starting application with FirstActivity,

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent1, CODE);
```

works well. However, starting application with TabActivity,

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost
    .newTabSpec("tabmenu")
    .setIndicator("menu1")
    .setContent(intent2));
```

then startActivityForResult(intent1, CODE) again, it only call SecondActivity but onActivityResult never called anymore.
I didn't change any code, but changing starting activity on AndroidManifest.xml.
What should I do calling onActivityResult with TabHost?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: onActivityResult is called when the Activity you started exits. With a TabHost, it doesn't exit until the containing TabActivity exits. You can use Fragments with the compatibility library, and call any public method in your activity from the Fragments any time you like.

Comment: @user999717 I'm really appreciate your comment! However, if then, I have a one more question, and one problem. In fact, FirstActivity should be contained within TabHost, but SecondActivity doesn't have to, so I think when SecondActviity finishes onActivityResult must be called. And.. I'm developing app on API 9, 10 but I know Fragment is able to use on API 11 or higher. Any other solution? or correct me if I had misunderstood.

Comment: 1. Yes, if you start the activity from your TabActivity it'll put the TabActivity on the back stack and when it finishes you'll get the result. 2. Right-click your project in Eclipse, Android Tools > Add Compatibility Library